# Which token from Google's Social Login API should you use for securing back-end data in a public-facing ReactJS app?

Tags: reactjs, google-signin

I am using the Google Sign-In API documented here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in to let users sign-in to a ReactJS app.

When control is back to the app, I see this json coming from the api:

```
{
"Ba": "999888988999898999999",
"wc": {
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "access_token": "ya99.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_Gt9hSnCbfgLfXXJpV9oGnJypUrN5cwrS8YBBHctEMLumSPhLDMmGEauaiHoTAWsdDTEY9OEaaAK9AeQa58pUp9SjiElHGMiU8UXT8cOpXyUMIXhXydHaMkXj",
    "scope": "email profile openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
    "login_hint": "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYpasAM9f89UaNK9wHcHDJrcH-KAPpI99eCwn8CdOE5YFBtCJQDCqaaI9pLyaaRqA",
    "expires_in": 9599,
    "id_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUaI9NiIsImtpaCI8IjNkaDajYTJhODFkYaJmaWE9YaM9NDI9MaFlN9UyOTakMmQ9NWI9NDYiLCJ9eXAiOiJKV9QifQ.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.HYIamlf98xyo9ah9WennYB8ob8N9JaOxs8drmA8PdOy89emO8R_UVn9_F9YmKsBicMYMmUeis-9_hBijayOahDXQuEhu8gm8AsAhdq5GfP89hfb9G9h9UyPEdMWb9y9w-q9EayXsArDp9A9yT8AGGaRpF5i-tNmtwL8mlDJaFyh9UuIMlyCpYjhyD9lbCvGcVI9dbogcMkal-PnxY9S58Uw8SFsyOLJqWk9bTmQNqjQrwbBooWav99IxcDXjnJixmp9naTxBqAv5J9mEpFwQKbKSbbcNraJQLJvuacVEAVCR9ueOVOXlbOehj8b8SRlB89rrjgjmrqb9LdsMit8kew",
    "session_state": {
        "extraQueryParams": {
            "authuser": "9"
        }
    },
    "first_issued_at": 9898599895889,
    "expires_at": 9898599999889,
    "idpId": "google"
},
"Du": {
    "FW": "999888988999898999999",
    "tf": "Test User",
    "VX": "Test",
    "iW": "User",
    "eN": "https://lh9.googleusercontent.com/a/AATXAJxva9fSnDkJjI9K_b9Afu9_Gha9qc-XdIYmsKr8=s98-c",
    "tv": "xxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com"
},
"googleId": "999888988999898999999",
"tokenObj": {
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "access_token": "ya99.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_Gt9hSnCbfgLfXXJpV9oGnJypUrN5cwrS8YBBHctEMLumSPhLDMmGEauaiHoTAWsdDTEY9OEaaAK9AeQa58pUp9SjiElHGMiU8UXT8cOpXyUMIXhXydHaMkXj",
    "scope": "email profile openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
    "login_hint": "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYpasAM9f89UaNK9wHcHDJrcH-KAPpI99eCwn8CdOE5YFBtCJQDCqaaI9pLyaaRqA",
    "expires_in": 9599,
    "id_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUaI9NiIsImtpaCI8IjNkaDajYTJhODFkYaJmaWE9YaM9NDI9MaFlN9UyOTakMmQ9NWI9NDYiLCJ9eXAiOiJKV9QifQ.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.HYIamlf98xyo9ah9WennYB8ob8N9JaOxs8drmA8PdOy89emO8R_UVn9_F9YmKsBicMYMmUeis-9_hBijayOahDXQuEhu8gm8AsAhdq5GfP89hfb9G9h9UyPEdMWb9y9w-q9EayXsArDp9A9yT8AGGaRpF5i-tNmtwL8mlDJaFyh9UuIMlyCpYjhyD9lbCvGcVI9dbogcMkal-PnxY9S58Uw8SFsyOLJqWk9bTmQNqjQrwbBooWav99IxcDXjnJixmp9naTxBqAv5J9mEpFwQKbKSbbcNraJQLJvuacVEAVCR9ueOVOXlbOehj8b8SRlB89rrjgjmrqb9LdsMit8kew",
    "session_state": {
        "extraQueryParams": {
            "authuser": "9"
        }
    },
    "first_issued_at": 9898599895889,
    "expires_at": 9898599999889,
    "idpId": "google"
},
"tokenId": "eyJhbGciOiJSUaI9NiIsImtpaCI8IjNkaDajYTJhODFkYaJmaWE9YaM9NDI9MaFlN9UyOTakMmQ9NWI9NDYiLCJ9eXAiOiJKV9QifQ.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.HYIamlf98xyo9ah9WennYB8ob8N9JaOxs8drmA8PdOy89emO8R_UVn9_F9YmKsBicMYMmUeis-9_hBijayOahDXQuEhu8gm8AsAhdq5GfP89hfb9G9h9UyPEdMWb9y9w-q9EayXsArDp9A9yT8AGGaRpF5i-tNmtwL8mlDJaFyh9UuIMlyCpYjhyD9lbCvGcVI9dbogcMkal-PnxY9S58Uw8SFsyOLJqWk9bTmQNqjQrwbBooWav99IxcDXjnJixmp9naTxBqAv5J9mEpFwQKbKSbbcNraJQLJvuacVEAVCR9ueOVOXlbOehj8b8SRlB89rrjgjmrqb9LdsMit8kew",
"accessToken": "ya99.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_Gt9hSnCbfgLfXXJpV9oGnJypUrN5cwrS8YBBHctEMLumSPhLDMmGEauaiHoTAWsdDTEY9OEaaAK9AeQa58pUp9SjiElHGMiU8UXT8cOpXyUMIXhXydHaMkXj",
"profileObj": {
    "googleId": "999888988999898999999",
    "imageUrl": "https://lh9.googleusercontent.com/a/AAXXXXXXXI9K_b9Afu9_Gha9qc-XdIYmsKr8=s98-c",
    "email": "xxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com",
    "name": "Test User",
    "givenName": "Test",
    "familyName": "User"
}
```

}

Now I want to store some data associated with the logged-in user, for example, their site preferences, and associate it to their social login.

If this was a regular non-social user with just an ID and Password, I would use a secret derived from the ID & password to authenticate the user to a custom back-end API when storing and retrieving the data. This way an attacker hacking the ReactJS app cannot retrieve information associated with a different user.

However with this social login, there is no password. What should I use instead from the Google Response to secure the call to the back-end?

I presume I need a token which is generated by Google, and is permanent as well as unique to both the user and my web app. Unless I'm doing something completely wrong and what I need is for the back-end API to talk to Google directly. How is this supposed to work?

**WHAT HAVE I TRIED SO FAR**

I have placed a `console.log()` call after the Google API call, which let me inspect the json returned as per the above. Then I realized the json is not self-explanatory at all, and this is not something I can solve by trial-and-error. Also, I checked the documentation and discovered that it says nothing about this scenario.

Comment: You should send the Id Token along with Access Token (if needed) to your backend service and let your backend validate everything using Google's libraries. In the documentation check the section that is called [Authenticate with a backend server](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth). I would also urge to not use this library that you've linked because it is getting deprecated. You should use the new Google Identity Services SDKs.